# How do I change border style using [style.border] when a question is answered?

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble changing border style from $vivid-blue to $medium-gray when the question is answered.
This is my code:

```
<section id="question" [style.border]="!answer ? 'unanswered': 'answered'">
```

and in the SCSS I have

```
.unanswered {
  border: 2px solid $vivid-blue !important;
}

.answered {
  border: 2px solid $medium-gray !important;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to assign a class to a style. it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Tried <section id="question" [style.borderColor]="!answer ? '$vivid-blue': '$medium-gray'"> and <section id="question" [style.border]="!answer ? '2px solid $vivid-blue': '2px solid $medium-gray'"> they both show up initially as blue but do not change to gray.

Comment: try using an actual Boolean variable for your operator. "answer" doesn't sound like a boolean.

Comment: yes answer is a number[ ]

Comment: if its a number why are you using "!answer" syntax instead of "answer==0"? it probably not your problem, but its better coding.

Comment: also, not familiar with dollar signs in html like that. if that's a css thing it may not be working in html

Comment: got it working, <section id="question" [style.border]="!answer || answer.length === 0 ? '2px solid blue': '2px solid gray'">

Comment: the dollar sign are part of SCSS, but cannot be used in your html. try using [ngClass] if you want to take advantage of the SCSS variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
<section id="question" [ngClass]="!answer ? 'unanswered': 'answered'">
```

or this:

```
<section id="question" [style.border]="!answer ? 'border: 2px solid blue !important': 'border: 2px solid gray !important'">
```

Comment: edited my answer to take out the dollar signs in the html

Comment: Ok this seems to do the trick:  <section id="question" [ngClass]="!answer || answer.length === 0 ? 'unanswered': 'answered'">

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngClass` to apply the class name conditionally as following:

```html
<section id="question" [ngClass]="answer ? 'answered': 'unanswered'">
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same moving the logic code to your component:

```js
public applyClass(): string {
   return (this.answer) ? 'answered' : 'unanswered'
}
```

Completing this in your template:

```html
<section id="question" [ngClass]="applyClass()">
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```html
<section id="question" [ngClass]="!answer ? 'unanswered': 'answered'">
```

or

```html
<section id="question" [class.answered]="answer" [class.unanswered]="!answer">
```

or

```html
<section id="question" [ngClass]="{answered: answer, unanswered: !answer}">
```

if you want to use style not a class then it will be like

```html
<section id="question" class="calls" [style.border-color]="!answer ? 'blue': 'gray'">
```

and in your css

```css
.calls {
  border: 2px solid !important;
}
```